# How to select single specific element between two elements using xpath

Tags: xpath

[image]

I want to select Element button [...] which is between **Consulting Services** and **Supervisory Organization**. I tried many xpath with preceding and following but it always select element **Supervisory Organization**

Latest Xpath I tried :

```
(//div[text()='Consulting Services']/following::div[text()='Supervisory Organization'])[1][//preceding::ul//img[@title='Related Actions and Preview']]
```

**Html :**

```
<div class="WPJF">
    <div class="WDVV WAUV WJ3 WEWV WCWV WDKF WAKF" data-automation-id="compositeHeader" id="56$284553">
        <div class="WIVV">
            <ul tabindex="-2" class="WIEP WHVV" role="presentation" data-automation-id="selectedItemList">
                <li class="WMEP" role="presentation">
                    <div class="WCEP WLEP" tabindex="-2" id="fac7048965494633a57cb15651618375" data-automation-id="menuItem" aria-label="Consulting Services, press delete to clear value." role="presentation" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="1">
                        <div class="WDEP">
                            <div class="WMJN WKIN WCJN" data-automation-id="selectedItem_2500$199">
                                <ul class="WAJN"></ul>
                                <div class="gwt-Label WNJN WKIN" data-automation-id="promptOption" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-443" data-automation-label="Consulting Services" title="Consulting Services" aria-label="Consulting Services" role="link" tabindex="0">Consulting Services</div>
                                <ul class="WAJN WFJN" role="presentation">
                                    <li class="WLJN"><img class="gwt-Image WLQO WFVP WPWP WBJN" src="https://impl.workday.com/wday/uiclient/static/gwt-desktop/update/WorkdayApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" data-automation-id="RELATED_TASK_charm" alt="" aria-label="Related Actions and Preview" title="Related Actions and Preview" aria-labelledby="promptOption-gwt-uid-443"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-automation-id="wd-MoreLink" data-automation-morelinkexpanded="false" role="button" id="968c25d5792a4c2eaf6ca6028f1e8fdf" class="WK3P WJ3P" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><img class="gwt-Image WLQO WN3P" src="https://impl.workday.com/wday/uiclient/static/gwt-desktop/update/WorkdayApp/8CB9E57BEDDE62E4F67DEB6E19F5308C.cache.png" draggable="false" alt=""><span class="WO3P" data-automation-id="moreLinkLabel" title="" aria-label="More (-4)"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div aria-readonly="true" class="wd-Text WAUY WMUY WJ3 WIKF WAKF" data-automation-id="compositeSubHeaderTwo" id="56$284555" dir="ltr">Supervisory Organization</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to share the relevant HTML to get a good answer.

Comment: can u provide the source for the given div?

Comment: @zx485 - html Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can first find the `img` in the `ul` and then specify the `preceding` and the `following`.

```
//ul//img[@title='Related Actions and Preview'][preceding::div[text()='Consulting Services'] and following::div[text()='Supervisory Organization']]
```

If you want to select only the first one, you can wrap the expression between parenthesis and use the index.

```
(//ul//img[@title='Related Actions and Preview'][preceding::div[text()='Consulting Services'] and following::div[text()='Supervisory Organization']])[1]
```

Comment: I tried it. It returns me 22 nodes. I want to select first one. Should I depends on index?

Comment: @HelpingHands I have added getting only the first one to my answer.